# c# trying to get an event to fire when a different window closes

Tags: c#, events

I have one form that has an option to open another (dialogue). I want an event to fire when the second window closes. The first form is named frmMain() the other is frmAddEmployee(). Heres what I have:
 in frmMain()

```
//create and open the second window
public void (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmAddEmployee addEmp = new frmAddEmployee();
     addEmp.ShowDialogue();
}

//create event to handle addEmp being closed
public void addEmp_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PopulateEmployeeList();
}
```

I'm not sure the event is being recognized as an event. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events in C# have to be registered manually - the C# compiler will not automatically register method as an event handler based just on the name of the method. You need:

```
 frmAddEmployee addEmp = new frmAddEmployee(); 
 addEmp.Closing += addEmp_Closing; // Register event handler explicitly
 addEmp.ShowDialogue();
```

Automatic registration of events is done in ASP.NET and Visual Basic has `Handles` clause, but in C#, you need to use the `+=` operator to specify that some method should be called when an event occurs.

Comment: @Aaron : I tried to smack you with a -1 for being a smarty, but I accidentally hit +1 instead! :P

Comment: @Andrew I'll take what I can get :D

Comment: aha, thanks. Maybe its vs 2010, but the actual property was addEmp.FormClosing. Just a side thought though. This isn't going to add that register that event as a new event every time the window is opened, is it?

Comment: @Sineasthetic, you are creating a new instance each time, so it will register the event handler for each instance.  Also, see my answer - if you want to use ShowDialog, you don't need the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ShowDialogue means ShowDialog, then it shows the form modally and you don't need an event handler:

```
//create and open the second window
public void (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmAddEmployee addEmp = new frmAddEmployee();
     addEmp.ShowDialog();
     PopulateEmployeeList();
}
```

If you don't show the second form modally, then you can hook up the event handler before showing the form like this:

```
public void (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmAddEmployee addEmp = new frmAddEmployee();
     addEmp.FormClosed += AddEmpClosed;
     addEmp.Show();
}

private void AddEmpClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     PopluateEmployeeList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `Closing` and `Closed` events which you can register for on the `Form`. You are registered for neither, unless your registration is taking place somehwere else?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `addEmp.ShowDialog()` you need to set your method to handle the Closing event:

```
frmAddEmployee addEmp = new frmAddEmployee();
addEmp.Closing += addEmp_Closing;
addEmp.ShowDialogue();
```